# Option parsing issue with python click

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I am using click for arg/option parsing in python scripts. I have a script, which accepts two options (both are mandatory) and i can run this script as below.

```
pgm.py --option1 val1 --option2 val2
```

Now if we miss giving value for option1, click complains that option2 is missing (quire misleading)

```
pgm.py --option1 --option2 val2
```

here @click is assuming option1's value as --option2 and searching for option2 param which it couldn't find.

```
@click.command()
@click.option("--option1", required=True)
@click.option("--option2", required=True)
def main(option1, option2):
    print(f"option1={option1} option2={option2}")
```

I searched documentation for any relevant option to parse this properly (there should be one), couldn't find any. Even tried callbacks to validate None type/null, that didn't help either as we are getting option name as option value. One way to fix this is to have custom logic in callback function to check if value is starting with -- (not so clean). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That seems to be the expected behavior: `--option1` requires a value, and the way you've written the command line, `--option2` is that value. That's common behavior for command line tools.

Comment: @larsks is there a way we can let click parser know that option1 value is missing here and not to consider "--option2" as a value?

Comment: There is not. What if you *want* an option to accept values that start with `-`? Your best bet is to add a validator that throws a warning or error if the option values starts with `-` (`curl` throws a warning: try e.g. `curl --output --fail https://google.com`).

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that even in this situation...

```
pgm.py --option1 --option2 val2
```

...the script will still (correctly) exit with an error, because you will be missing a value of `--option2`. Running the above command would result in:

```
Error: Missing option '--option2'.
```

For the behavior you want, you can add a simple validator; for
example:

```py
import click


def errorOnFlagValue(val):
    if val.startswith('-'):
        raise ValueError()

    return val


@click.command()
@click.option('--option1', required=True, type=errorOnFlagValue)
@click.option('--option2', required=True, type=errorOnFlagValue)
def main(option1, option2):
    print(f'option1={option1}, option2={option2}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running the command line from the beginning of this answer would
result in:

```
Error: Invalid value for '--option1': --option2
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks. Aware of custom callbacks, but I am searching for a way to do this with out this. Similar to required=True (which checks for presence of option), i believe there should be an option to make value mandatory.

Comment: Setting `required=True` *does* make the value mandatory. You're asking to set specific requirements on the format of the value, which is what custom validators are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try nessaid-cli package to do extra validation of CLI tokens. The CLI can be specified with a rich grammar which supports complex CLI options and combinations. The CLI can be run as an interactive shell or standalone script.

The framework is available at [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/nessaid-cli/) and [github](https://github.com/saithalavi/nessaid_cli)

The basic CLI in the question can be implemented like this

```
import sys
import asyncio
from nessaid_cli.cmd import NessaidCmd
from nessaid_cli.tokens import StringToken;


class TestCli(NessaidCmd):
    r"""
    token OPTION1 StringToken(), OPTION2 StringToken();
    """

    def get_token_classes(self):
        """Method to override.
        It should return the list of token classes being used"""
        return [StringToken]

    def do_command1(self, option1, option2):
        r"""
        "--option1"
        OPTION1
        "--option2"
        OPTION2
        <<
            $option1 = $2;
            $option2 = $4;
        >>
        """
        print(f"option1={option1} option2={option2}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(TestCli.execute_args(*sys.argv[1:]))
```

This will not accept **pgm.py --option1 --option2 val2** since we have all 4 CLI tokens mandatory.

Here's the output

```sh
C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --option1 A --option2 B
option1=A option2=B

C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --option1 1 --option2 2
option1=1 option2=2

C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --option1 --option1 --option2 2
option1=--option1 option2=2

C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --option1 --option2 --option2 --option1
option1=--option2 option2=--option1
```

Now the following passes because we have auto-complete and position of keywords in the above CLI are fixed

```sh
C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --option --option2 --opt --option1
option1=--option2 option2=--option1
```

The following fails because it expects --option2 as 3rd argument

```sh
C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --option --option2 option2 2
Result: failure
Error: Could not match any rule for this sequence
```

The following fails because the 4th argument is missing.

```
C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --option --option2 --option2
Result: partial
Error: Input sequence is not complete
```

The next example shows how we can define custom tokens. In this, we can validate the tokens. Here, we are preventing "--option1" and "--option2" as input values.

```py
import sys
import asyncio
from nessaid_cli.cmd import NessaidCmd
from nessaid_cli.tokens import StringToken, MATCH_FAILURE, MATCH_SUCCESS;


class ValidOptions(StringToken):

    def match(self, token_input):
        if token_input in ["--option1", "--option2"]:
            return MATCH_FAILURE
        return MATCH_SUCCESS

class TestCli(NessaidCmd):
    r"""
    token OPTION1 ValidOptions(), OPTION2 ValidOptions();
    """

    def get_token_classes(self):
        """Method to override.
        It should return the list of token classes being used"""
        return [ValidOptions]

    def do_command1(self, option1, option2):
        r"""
        "--option1"
        OPTION1
        "--option2"
        OPTION2
        <<
            $option1 = $2;
            $option2 = $4;
        >>
        """
        print(f"option1={option1} option2={option2}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(TestCli.execute_args(*sys.argv[1:]))
```

And the bhavior changes like this

```sh
C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --op 1 --op 2
option1=1 option2=2

C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --op --option1 --op 2
Result: failure
Error: Could not match any rule for this sequence

C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --op option1 --op 2
option1=option1 option2=2

C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --op option1 --op --option2
Result: failure
Error: Could not match any rule for this sequence

C:\Users\Said\Desktop>python clitest.py --op option1 --op --option3
option1=option1 option2=--option3
```